# I did docker system prune to delete unused images but deleted everything is there way to undo this?

Tags: java, kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-image, dockerhub

I did docker system prune to delete unused images but deleted everything is there way to undo this? is there any ways to fix this out?

Answer (score 2):

Hello, sorry for my answer but its a nope...

When you use the prune command you are prompted to know if you are sure or not, sadly this is a last warning before the drama :D

Hope you still got the dockerfile to rebuild your own images, if they came from internet, just go back from where you get them :D (Try your browser history if you do not remember)

Keep the smile bro ! :)
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/

Comment: my docker prune murdered my externally mapped harddrives.. seems pretty dumb they map all data to a virtuel harddrive .. and then it's not associated with a container, so it gets deleted when pruning..